# Is the random slope for a binary, categorical variable in a mixed model also reported in reference to one of the categories?

Tags: mixed-model, binary-data, probit, intercept

I'm wondering if I should be interpreting an estimated random slope for a binary categorical variable in the same way that I should be interpreting it if it were a fixed effect. That is, is it reported as a comparison against a reference.

So for example, I'm analyzing mini-golf performance and trying to assess how player handedness impacts the probability of a hole-in-one while controlling for random effects for multiple observations at each hole and for each player. So the model looks like:

```
glmer(hoi ~ hand + (hand | hole) + (1 | player), 
      family = binomial(link ='probit'), data = minigolf)
```

For the fixed effects, the model intercept is **-1.96** and the intercept for handRight is **-0.018**. So the expected probability, assuming the average player and hole, for lefties is

```
-1.96 %>% pnorm
```

and for righties, it is

```
(-1.96 - 0.018) %>% pnorm
```

The model also reports a random intercept and slope for handedness for each hole. So let's say the intercept and slope for hole1 is **-.11** and **.019**, respectively. Would calculating the expected value for lefties on that hole, assuming average players, then be

```
(-1.96 - .11) %>% pnorm
```

and the probability for righties be

```
(-1.96 - 0.018 -.11 +.019) %>% pnorm
```

?. That is, is the slope for handedness in a random effect also reported in reference to lefties, which would be reflected in the random intercept alone?